# Am I proving this statement with itself?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

For a homework problem, I need to prove that given a nonempty set of real numbers $S$ that is bounded above, with $b = \sup S$, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a number $a \in S$ such that $b - \epsilon < a \leq b$.  My current proof looks separately at the case where $b \in S$, which is trivial, and the case where $b \notin S$.  My current proof that we can find such a value $a$ in the second case relies on the fact that there must be some real number $r \in S$, necessarily less than $b$, for which the continuous interval $[r, b)$ is a subset of S.

I'm wondering whether or not the assumption that we can construct such an interval is valid for this proof.  It seems to me that the statement I'm proving is a reason that we can construct such an interval, so relying on that assumption would be to try to prove the statement with itself.  Should I find another approach to proving this, or is my current method valid and I'm really worried over nothing?

Comment: You need to use the definition of 'sup' in your proof

Comment: You can not assume this: Whats the sup of $S=\{1-\frac{1}{n}|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$? Does $S$ contain any intervals?

Comment: @Zestylemonzi That's a very good point.  It did not occur to me that such sets exist.

Comment: I'd go with proof by contradiction for this one - what happens if there doesn't exist such $a$....then all $a \in S$ satisfy $a \le S - \epsilon$.......can you continue from here?

Comment: If, for some $\epsilon>0$, you have $S \subset (-\infty,b-\epsilon]$, then you can see that $b-\epsilon$ is an upper bound for $S$ that is strictly less than $b$, which contradicts $b=\sup S$. In particular, this means that $(b-\epsilon, b] \cap S$ is non empty for all $\epsilon>0$. Choose any $a$ from this intersection.

Comment: Considering how most proofs we've done so far involving suprema were by contradiction, I'm not sure why I didn't start with that in the first place (maybe because I was given the impression in a previous course that proofs by contradiction are inherently less nice than direct proofs).  Thanks for all the help, everyone.